# an example of a sequence of random variables $X_n$ that converges to $X$ in the first moment but not almost surely?

Tags: probability

what is an example of a sequence of random variables $X_n$ that converges to $X$ in the first moment but not almost surely?

I think it is not possible!!
because we need to have, the probability that $X_n$ and $X$ differ, really small or that $X_n$ and $X$ differ very little in order to get convergence in the first moment. We don't want them to converge almost surely.

We want that they don't converge a.s so we want the probability that they differ large. Well we can only do so if they differ by little.

I can't think of an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a sequence of independent random variables $X_n$ where $\mathbb P(X_n=1)=\frac1n$ and $\mathbb P(X_n=0)=1-\frac1n$:

Then $X_n$ converges to $0$ in first moment (I would say "in mean") since $\mathbb E[|X_n-0)|]= \frac1n \to 0$, and indeed  $X_n$ converges to $0$ in all moments

But $X_n$ does not converge to $0$ almost surely, since for all $N$ and $\epsilon$ you have $\sum\limits_{n=N+1}^{\infty} P(|X_n-0| \ge \min(1,\epsilon))=\infty $ and so $\mathbb P\left( \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\! X_n = 0 \right) = 0 \not = 1$

Comment: sorry sir, I don't understand why $\sum\limits_{n=N+1}^{\infty} P(|X_n-0| \ge \min(1,\epsilon))=\infty $ ? I understand that convergence in first moment implies convergence in probability. So from that we get $P(|X_n-0| \geq \epsilon)\to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. So how can we get a sum of infinity?

Comment: @user42493 Because each probability is $\frac1n$ and while $\frac1n \to 0$ you have $\sum\frac1n \to \infty$.  In particular  $\sum\limits_{n=N+1}^{k} \frac1n\approx \log_e(k) -\log_e(N)$ as the difference between two harmonic sums and that difference tends to infinity as $k$ increases